# How to deserialize a json array with multiple data types?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I now need to deserialize a JSON that looks like this:

```json
{
    "arguments": {
        "game": [
            "--username",
            "--version",
            "--assetsDir",
            {
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "action": "allow",
                        "features": {
                            "is_demo_user": true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "value": "--demo"
            },
            {
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "action": "allow",
                        "features": {
                            "has_custom_resolution": true
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "value": [
                    "--width",
                    "--height"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

As you can see, the array named "game" has **both** "value" and "object" in it. (But the fact is **WORSE** than this example, the number of elements is **NOT certain**)

And the data type of `arguments.game[*].value` is **NOT certain**, too.

I used to use classes to describe it, but deserialization failed.

Can't seem to describe an array with multiple element types with a class?

I am using Json.NET. Is there any way to deserialize this "game" array.

Thanks.

Comment: 1) It's `arguments.game` not `arguments`, right?  2) Do the contents of the ``arguments.game[]` array have a fixed scheme, i.e. always three strings and two objects, or are they variable?  Can you [edit] your question to share the *classes to describe it* that you tried?  Do the `arguments.game[*]` **object** have some sort of fixed schema that you know a priori?

Comment: Also `arguments.game[*].value` seems to have multiple data types: sometimes a string, sometimes an array of strings.  Do you know the possible types of values this might contain?

Comment: If everything is uncertain your best bet may be to deserialize to a [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm).  Unlike `ExpandoObject` or `dynamic` it is explicitly designed to allow for queries, see [Querying JSON with LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/queryinglinqtojson.htm) and [Querying JSON with complex JSON Path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm).

Comment: I am always wondering how somebody can write the code to deserialize data if this person even don't know what kind of data json contains and what data is needed. It doesn't make any sense. You are just waisting our time with this kind of question. Have some respesct to another people. Deside at first what data you need, after this how it could be obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a requirement to deserialize to an instance of a class? You could use an ExpandoObject:

```
using System.Dynamic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
string json = @"{
""arguments"": {
    ""game"": [
        ""--username"",
        ""--version"",
        ""--assetsDir"",
        {
            ""rules"": [
                {
                    ""action"": ""allow"",
                    ""features"": {
                        ""is_demo_user"": true
                    }
                }
            ],
            ""value"": ""--demo""
        },
        {
            ""rules"": [
                {
                    ""action"": ""allow"",
                    ""features"": {
                        ""has_custom_resolution"": true
                    }
                }
            ],
            ""value"": [
                ""--width"",
                ""--height""
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}";

var expConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, expConverter);
```

The `obj` variable will contain the result of the JSON conversion, then you can traverse the dynamic object in code.

For example, to get a list of strings under 'game':

```
IList<object> list = new List<object>(obj.arguments.game);
foreach (object str in list)
{
    if (str as string != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str as string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me a sample code such as listing all the 'strings' in the 'games' array?

Comment: like output:  `--username --version --assetsDir`

Comment: I've updated the answer above.